# Is [nextsibling] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Saw the [nextsibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextsibling) tag for the first time today and it struck me as a very odd thing to have a tag about. It's hyper specialised, for one thing. And I can't even think of somebody who could be an expert in [nextsibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nextsibling) which is my usual first test for tags. Also, it appears that there are 52 questions tagged with it as of this time

Some highest voted questions do seem to be literally talk about this property, which makes the tag somewhat on point there, I agree. However, I can't think of a reason I'd go and look for that tag if I have trouble:

1. With DOM navigation
2. In JavaScript
3. The problem is specifically with using `element.nextSibling`

Comment: Seems pretty useless to me. If this is okay, why not have a tag for every property of every type in every library of every language?

Comment: The tag expert argument is complete nonsense by the way, and it has never been a valid argument for removing a tag.

Comment: @TinyGiant not as a sole criteria, I agree. I use it as a smell test. If you cannot be an "expert" on the subject of some tag, then it bears a second look if the tag is actually needed. And when I took a second look at `nextsibling` I really couldn't find a value in it, hence why I posted it here to see if anybody else does.

Comment: The tag seems to be doing a good job of classifying questions, and it doesn't meet any of the established burnination criteria. The value is in its ability to classify questions, which it is doing just fine.

Comment: @TinyGiant is any classification automatically good? What if we had a tag `green` used you want to draw a green line? I reviewed the burnination guidelines and it fails 3 out of the 4. It doesn't describe the content of the question very well (1.) - the knowledge that you have at least one line with `.nextSibling` in it means nothing. It doesn't add value for the same reason (3.). It doesn't mean the same thing, as it's already used for non-JS and non-DOM questions. It only covers 2. - it's "on topic". In that it's used during programming. Feel free to post an answer, to explain the usefulness

Comment: Haven't you heard of a first-child/next-sibling tree?

Comment: @Joshua I have. But the tag is not about those. It's *specifically* about the `nextSibling` property of HTML DOM nodes in JavaScript.

Comment: @VLAZ: Except for two nice XML questions.

Comment: @Joshua And the questions that aren't about JS at all. The tag description literally says "A read-only property of javascript that return sibling text after target element.". The wiki info is the specs for what `nextSibling` returns. So, that makes all those questions mistagged.

Comment: _"A read-only property of javascript that return **sibling text after target element**."_ What? No.

Comment: If people are asking about the DOM API property nextSibling then it absolutely describes the content of the question well and is valuable for that reason so I disagree with your assessment. Is this tag actively causing harm? Absolutely not. People using a tag for something other than the intended usage does not mean that it means multiple things, it jist means that people sometimes misuse it, as is life.

Comment: If the tag is kept, I'll create the corresponding `[previoussibling]` one.

Comment: You are amazed by a tag for a specific property, what about .NET's [tag:console.readline]? It's a single method and it has a dedicated tag. Every time I mention this, someone claims that these tags are harmless and so should be left as they are

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto tell them, that these tags are occuping the place of other more important ones. .Net tends to have multiple libraries (which are several times more important, no?). Remember them that you can have only 5 tags, each one has to count (I presume you already mentioned that each tag has to stand on its own, right)

Comment: @Braiam thats nonsense. If someone is asking about the console.readline method, then that tag is absolutely applicable. The fact that some  people misuse tags does not mean we should just burn the whole lot of them.

Comment: The tag (and method) are not just used on JS, they're used across PHP, Python, C#, PERL and in XPath. But still, I don't think it merits a tag, and can be deleted; plaintext search will find 100% of these. The tags [tag:DOM] or [tag:xpath] may be applicable.

Comment: So far, going by votes 48 people have expressed interest in the question and 3 have expressed that it's not very good for one reason or another. There is a single answer that the tag is about SEO which 2 people seem to agree with and 32 don't. Few comments mentioned that the tag is indeed useful (other than SEO) but nobody really bothered to write an answer to that effect which implies to me that there is not much very investment in that being the case. So, overall I'm left wondering when is this needed. Or *if*.

Answer (score -33):

Well, I am good at SEO too, so I think it is useful if someone searches for `nextSibling` property on Google. The first site will come is obviously w3schools or tutorial point. but it also helps Stack Overflow to rank the question on search engines when someone searched for the question regarding the following tag.

These tags can be used as helper tags with JavaScript and jQuery to identify the question more accurately that it is specific to the `nextSibling`.

But still, questions can be put up like...

- `nextSibling` is not working I don't know what's wrong unable to debug it?
- Should I use `nextSibling` or not my HTML is dynamic?
- My layout is getting messed-up after deleting `nextSibling` from my HTML dynamically?

as mentioned under tag section create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site. You cannot create a tag for every property, function etc but still, tags similar to this one exist which helps search engine and other users when someone searches for a related question.

similar tags example:

- [head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/head) (685 Questions) why head tag exist?
- [onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/onclick) (11498) onclick is event? why is this tag exits? should be deleted?
- [preg-grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-grep) (36 Qs) it is a function should be deleted?
- and so on.

**Points which makes this tag useful:**

1) this tag is important because it helps in searches related for nextsibling property. And those who think tags are not important in searching please, tags were created for the user- and search-friendliness. most of the users on StackOverflow come through search engines like google.

2) the tag is a label attached to someone or something for the purpose of identification or to give other information. I think this tag is passing useful information to the question if it is not the question should be edited and the tagged should be removed from the question for spamming.
if 10/52 questions nextsibling tag is providing useful information then it is not necessary to delete it.

Comment: " sooner or later this tag will automatically get deleted" Not if someone doesn't manually remove it from the questions that are already tagged with it, it won't.

Comment: The new tag will now be available for all other community members to use, without needing the new tag privilege. It will also show up in the moderator tools new tag report.

However, note that:

on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.
Please create new tags responsibly!

Comment: @Michael it will ger remove automatically if no other question used it in 6 month of period I was pointing out that.

Comment: That's wrong. I think you're referring to [this task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48417/should-we-zap-the-low-occurrence-tags/48418#48418) which only removes tags that are only used once in the 6 months since they were created. This tag is already ineligible for that.

Comment: @Michael ohh, sorry michael, I have not read that it is already used 52 times. sorry, I will update my answer.

Comment: I don't think SEO is relevant for the existence of a tag.

Comment: That [tag:head] tag is actually pretty bad itself. The entire description is 
"Check if you should use html-head or unix-head instead." and yet the first question I see is about the head node *of a list datastructure*.

Comment: "You cannot create a tag for every property, function etc" You haven't explained why you think `nextSibling` is important enough to pass this bar.